# A dialog for registering

Tags: modal-windows, dialog

I have list of lessons. Users tap a lesson to open a dialog box.

In every (Android) dialog I want the user to be able to register for the lesson, and see the duration, in hours, of that lesson.

If the user has already registered I want to allow them to cancel their registration.

In my app, right now, a star symbol indicates a registered lesson.

**Questions**

- I don't know what buttons and icons to use in the dialog (a star, and an X for Cancel)?
- Do I add another button for closing the dialog?
- Or should a tap outside the dialog to close it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alon, welcome to UX.SE. We need a little more info in order to answer this question. What type of app do you have? Mobile? Desktop? Displaying lesson info within a dialog is unconventional. Was there a specific reason why a dialog is used? What does registering for a lesson mean? Is this more like a Favourite, to allow users to more readily access the lesson in the future or does it have more meaning? What happens when the user un-registers?

Comment: this is mobile app,I have list of lesson that each person can register to this lesson.
each Item in the list contain hours and the title of the lesson.

User can register to the lesson. click on the item in the list open dialog box for register.I thought that click on the list Item for register is little problematic , cause I have swipe in the app and the user can click by mistake. register to the lesson is that he will come to this lesson and he will take place in this lesson.(This is not  favorite).

I want to make it possible to register and cancel if the user registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's best to follow the standards

You're asking about a [dialog](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html) on Android.

**Dismissing a dialog box**

I recommend you do what the [Android style guide says](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior) to do:

> Dialogs can be dismissed by touching/clicking outside of the dialog or by using the system back button (Android). Dialog behavior can be overridden so that users must explicitly choose one of the actions.

There's no reason to override the default behaviour.

On the same page, the style guide says you can also provide a **Cancel** comand link, as illustrated:

[image: Android dialog that has a Cancel command link]

**Provide a Register or an Unregister button**

For the command links, why don't you use words instead of icons, the way the [Android styleguide illustrates](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-content):

[image: An Android dialog]

When the user isn't yet registered, the name of the command could be **Register**, **Join**, or **Add**, depending on the mental model you want to reinforce and the wording that your audience will always understand.

Similarly, when the user is already registered, the name of the command could be **Unregister**, **Drop**, **Leave**, or **Remove**.

I hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: I am talking about mobile device :) something like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: OK, I revised the answer for you. Interestingly, the entire answer comes from the link you provided.